# Activity is visible and clickable underneath fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Whenever I use my action bar to bring up a new fragment, whether it be a preference fragment or a custom one, the background is transparent and clickable. I can't simply set the background color to something because the user can still click through the fragment. Here is where I think the issue is at, but not sure.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {//Present list of options on action bar touch.
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            inSettings = true;
            break;
        }
        case R.id.probabiliy:
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new probabilityFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            inSettings = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an activity for your preference and an activity for your custom fragment unless the fragment is meant for your main activity. Then you will not have this problem.

A Fragment is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity. It is not an opaque. An activity is opaque. Think of an activity is a virtual window and a fragment is a super widget in an activity.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to solve this is to put background:color in your current fragment layout and key thing to put is android:clickable to true in same layout